# Bind many HashMaps to TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have some `HasMap`s in my app (2,3,4 or even 20) to keep things structured for faster "random" access. And I need to show values of all `HashMap`s in the `TableView` and keep tracking changes. I have no idea how to achieve this, so I tried this:

As I tested, in Java, all objects passes by reference. `ObservableList` is the list of references, `HashMap` full of references too, as I thought. So, I made this thing:

As object is added to `HashMap` as value of new entry, it must also be added to the `ObservableList`, like so:

```
class MyVeryOwnHashMap extends HashMap<String, MyObject> {

    private final ObservableList<MyObject> list;

    public MyVeryOwnHashMap(ObservableList<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public MyObject put(String key, MyObject value) {
        this.list.add(value); // As list was passed by reference, we have original list
        return super.put(key, value); // Adding to this hashmap also
        // value is the reference, so placed object is the same in both places
    }

    public MyObject remove(String name) {
       MyObject removed = super.remove(name);
       this.list.remove(removed); // Remove object from global list also
}
```

Things becomes simple:

```
ObservableList<MyObject> gList = FXCollections.observableList();
MyVeryOwnHashMap hashMap = new MyVeryOwnHashMap(gList);

JavaFXTable.setItems(gList);

MyObject obj = new MyObject("someNameProperty", "someValueProperty");
hashMap.put("objID", obj); // Now object shown on the GUI table as new row

["...Here is some chunk of meaningless code..."]

// Try to change some things
MyObj objWillChange = hashMap.get("objID"); // Should we get a reference to the same object?
objWillChange.setValueProperty("someOtherValue"); // Internally, each property is the SimpleStringProperty object
```

I wish to see the result of my gorgerous idea, but nothing happens! In the table still shown old `someValueProperty` :( As I said, my application can have alot of such `HashMap`s, I still have no idea, what I should to do.

Answer (score 0):

My [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (*without using your javafx classes since I don't have the lib installed*) shows that HashMap does indeed return the reference, and the object is having its value changed.

I made some minor corrections, such as changing `MyObj` to match `MyObject`, insert missing bracket at the end of `MyVeryOwnHashMap`, and returning the removed object from the `remove` method. Obviously I also created my own `MyObject` class.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<MyObject> gList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        MyVeryOwnHashMap hashMap = new MyVeryOwnHashMap(gList);

        MyObject obj = new MyObject("someNameProperty", "someValueProperty");
        System.out.println("Obj:           " + obj.getValue());
        hashMap.put("objID", obj); 

        // Try to change some things
        MyObject objWillChange = hashMap.get("objID");
        objWillChange.setValueProperty("someOtherValue");

        System.out.println("=== After Change ===");
        System.out.println("Obj:           " + obj.getValue());
        System.out.println("hashMap:       " + hashMap.get("objID").getValue());
        System.out.println("objWillChange: " + objWillChange.getValue());
    }
}

class MyObject {
    String name;
    String value;

    public MyObject(String name, String value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValueProperty(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

class MyVeryOwnHashMap extends HashMap<String, MyObject> {

    private final List<MyObject> list;

    public MyVeryOwnHashMap(List<MyObject> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public MyObject put(String key, MyObject value) {
        this.list.add(value);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    public MyObject remove(String name) {
       MyObject removed = super.remove(name);
       this.list.remove(removed);
       return removed;
    }
}
```

As for where to check next, I would first make something similar to what I made here, but include your JavaFX classes. Then start adding additional code up to what you have now until you discover at what point it messes up.